# How can I access agents loaded to another agent by Pickup?

Tags: anylogic

I want to read some parameters from part-agents which I loaded to a container-agent by the Pickup-Block. I have access to the container-agent and want to read variables and parameters from the part-agents. How can I access them?
Thanks for helping!

Answer (score 0):

your question is very vague but you can access the contents of a container using the `contents()` method, see below.

You can then loop across all agents and access their params or variables as you wish:
[image]

Also see the Help on Pickup: https://help.anylogic.com/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.anylogic.help%2Fhtml%2F_ProcessModeling%2FPickup.html&resultof=%22%70%69%63%6b%75%70%22%20

Comment: Hi Benjamin, thanks for your fast help! Finally I found the error. It was not caused by the pickup-block as I assumed... When creating the part-agent in code, I forgot to initialize parameters by ".setParametersToDefault()" before setting my own parameters. If you dont mind, I will delete this question, as it will not help anybody else...

Comment: Better to rephrase it properly and provide your own answer, then future folks can benefit as well ;-) (and you yourself should you forget again). Glad you found it

Comment: Although I have never used that function, tbh. Normally not necessary...